# Get Purchase Order Rule Data via repository Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.3.1, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.5p1

How to get Purchase order Rules data via repository.

Further, from the result I want to fetch the data of the column 'conditions_serialized'

Anyone who can guide ?

Comment: you mean you want to cart price rule via repository?

Comment: Hi, Yes but I did this. Thanks